# AngularJS factory inject other factories possible?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, factory

Here are 3 angular factories I have:

```
angular.module('myApp', []); 

angular.module('myApp').factory('**ClassA**', function() {
    return {
        object: {"id":-1, "name": "abc"}
    };
});


angular.module('myApp').factory('**ClassB**', function() {
    return {
        object : {"city":"cc","state":"NJ"} 
          };
});


angular.module('myApp').factory('**ClassAB**', function() {
    return {
        object:{ 
            ClassA: {"id":-1, "name":"pqr"},
            ClassB: {"city":"aa", "state":"NY"}
        }
    };
});
```

Is there a way to include or refer ClassA and ClassB so that I do not have to duplicate the code again. Something like this that will **NOT** pass data back to ClassA or ClassB.

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('**ClassAB**', function(ClassA, ClassB){
    return {
        object:{ 
            "ClassA": ClassA.object,
            "ClassB": ClassB.object
        }
    };
});
```

I do not want data to be bound to Class A or B just the class reference ie in Controller when I say:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function($scope, $filter, ClassA, ClassB, ClassAB) {

    console.log("ClassA before:" +ClassA.object.name);
    ClassAB.object.classA.name="xyz";
    console.log("ClassAB :"ClassAB.object.ClassA.name);
    console.log("ClassA after:"ClassA.object.name);
}
```

I get:

```
ClassA before: abc 

ClassAB : xyz

ClassA after: xyz
```

I would like to see something like this:

```
ClassA before: abc

ClassAB : xyz

ClassA after: abc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services and Factories are singleton in Angularjs, they are passed by reference.

So, if you dont want change ClassA objects, just copy them and then modify them.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function($scope, $filter, ClassA, ClassB, ClassAB) {

    console.log("ClassA before:" +ClassA.object.name);
    var obj = ClassAB.object.classA.copy();
        obj.name = "xyz";
    //use temp_name as you want 
    console.log("ClassAB :"ClassAB.object.ClassA.name);
    console.log("ClassA after:"ClassA.object.name);
}
```

This will give to you

```
ClassA before: abc

ClassAB : xyz

ClassA after: abc
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the tip, I actually tried making a copy in the factory so that controller does not have to worry about it... makes it much cleaner  and accomplishes the same. 'angular.module('myApp').factory('**ClassAB**', function(ClassA, ClassB){
    return {
        object:{ 
            "ClassA": angular.copy(ClassA.object),
            "ClassB": angular.copy(ClassB.object)
        }
    };
});'

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to more carefully choose what is exposed publicly from your factory. Perhaps use setters and getters instead of exposing the object directly, since it is a singleton. It seems that all you want from `ClassA` and `ClassB` are starting values for `ClassAB`. Perhaps this approach will work better for you:

**factories**

```
angular.module('myApp', []); 

angular.module('myApp').factory('ClassA', function() {
    // "private" variable
    var defaults = {"id":-1, "name": "abc"};

    return {
        get: function(){return defaults;},
        set: function(obj){defaults = obj;}
    };
});


angular.module('myApp').factory('ClassB', function() {
    var defaults = {"city":"cc","state":"NJ"};
    return {
        get: function(){return defaults;},
        set: function(obj){defaults = obj;}
    };
});


angular.module('myApp').factory('ClassAB', function(ClassA,ClassB) {
    return {
        object:{ 
            ClassA: ClassA.get(),
            ClassB: ClassB.get()
        }
    };
});
```

**controller**

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function($scope, $filter, ClassA, ClassB, ClassAB) {

```
console.log("ClassA before:" +ClassA.get().name); // abc
ClassAB.object.classA.name="xyz";
console.log("ClassAB :"ClassAB.object.ClassA.name); // xyz
console.log("ClassA after:"ClassA.get().name); // abc
```

}